# How to stream a live video from a URL?

Tags: android, android-fragments, video-streaming, live-streaming

I want to embed this [link](http://121.58.202.110:8080/jpeg?cam=4) in my android application. I tried doing this, but the video won't load. Im also getting an error java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cctv, container, false);

    try {
        String cctv = "http://121.58.202.110:8080/jpeg?cam=4";
        VideoView videoView = getView().findViewById(R.id.cctvfragment);
        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(getActivity());
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
        Uri video = Uri.parse(cctv);
        videoView.setMediaController(null);
        videoView.setVideoURI(video);
        videoView.start();
        videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        Log.d("CctvDebug", "ERROR LOADING VIDEO");
    }
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the question, Native Video View is very limited when it comes to urls that are newer and is (*i think) no longer updated. try using the [Vitamio](https://www.vitamio.org/en/Download/) video player instead. It is very useful for a variety of streaming functionalities.

```
<io.vov.vitamio.widget.VideoView
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:id="@+id/VideoView"/>
```

Also, do not call `start()` method right away. Only call it on your `OnPreparedListener()` callback.

```
Vitamio.isInitialized(getApplicationContext());

mVideoView.setVideoPath(path);
mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
mVideoView.requestFocus();

mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        // optional need Vitamio 4.0
        mediaPlayer.setPlaybackSpeed(1.0f);
    }
});
```

Or you could also use [KickFlip](https://kickflip.io/). It's very easy to setup,

```
Kickflip.initWithApiKey(API_KEY, API_SECRET);
Kickflip.startBroadcastActivity(this, mBroadcastListener);
```

Edit:

So I tried working on the stream since yesterday. I wasn't able to work it out on vitamio (Unfortunately). Though tried using the url you gave and streamed it through the vlc app. Though I haven't tried it, you might be able to use [LibVLC](https://code.videolan.org/videolan/libvlc-android-samples) . I ended up using webview with some settings so that it will not look like its using webview.

```
webView = findViewById(R.id.wvWebview);

webView.loadUrl("http://121.58.202.110:8080/jpeg?cam=4");
webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

[image: sample stream]

Comment: I tried using vitamio, there are no errors, however there is no video playing in the application?

Comment: But the view is visible though?

Comment: Yes, could it be that the url is not possible to be embedded?

Comment: No, it is still possible. May I ask, why is it using jpeg in your link.

Comment: I dont own the video stream url, i dont know why it's using jpeg